# WebSocketBundle Symfony 4 integration

Tags: php, symfony, websocket, symfony4

I have problem with Symfony 4 integration with GeniusesOfSymfony/WebSocketBundle, routing file for pubsub is not loading.
Installed everything

`'gos/web-socket-bundle                    dev-master '
'gos/pubsub-router-bundle                 v0.3.2'`

Created file _/config/packages/gos_web_socket.yaml_ with content

```
gos_web_socket:
    server:
        port: 1337        #The port the socket server will listen on
        host: 127.0.0.1   #The host ip to bind to
        router:
           resources:
               - '%kernel.project_dir%/config/pubsub.yaml'
    topics:
        - "@app.topic.chat"
```

And file *'/config/pubsub.yaml'* with content

```
app_topic_chat:
    channel: 'app/chat/{first_user}/{second_user}'
    handler:
        callback: 'chat.topic' #related to the getName() of your topic
    requirements:
        first_user:
            pattern: '\d+' #accept all valid regex, don't put delimiters !
        second_user:
            pattern: '\d+'
```

Getting always error

```
!!  In DelegatingLoader.php line 37:
!!                                                                               
!!    Cannot load resource "/var/www/html/cms/config/pubsub.yaml".
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Eh, problem was in naming. 
It was

> - '%kernel.project_dir%/config/pubsub.yaml'

but need to be

> - '%kernel.project_dir%/config/pubsub.yml'

so **yml** not **yaml**

Comment: yes, but was not working with yaml this bundle, but now yes.